# https via basicHttpBinding in WCF

Tags: wcf

I'm trying to get https working with basicHttpBinding in WCF. The service seems to run fine, but when I try to run my client and when it gets to calling one of the methods on the service, I get the following exception:

Could not establish trust relationship for the SSL/TLS secure channel with authority 'sfs-111:20023'.

I've included my code and config files below. If anyone could help, I'd be very grateful.

Please note, I'm new to WCF.

HERE'S MY SERVICE APP.CONFIG:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>

    <!-- DEBUG - TURN ON TRACING -->
    <system.diagnostics>
        <sources>
            <source name="System.ServiceModel" switchValue="Information, ActivityTracing" propagateActivity="true">
                <listeners>
                    <add name="traceListener"
                            type="System.Diagnostics.XmlWriterTraceListener"
                            initializeData= "c:\tahseen\dd\WCFServer.svclog" />
                </listeners>
            </source>
        </sources>
    </system.diagnostics>

    <system.serviceModel>
        <behaviors>
            <serviceBehaviors>

                <!-- BEHAVIOR FOR META DATA -->
                <behavior name="DeltaServiceBehavior">
                    <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" />
                    <serviceCredentials>
                        <windowsAuthentication includeWindowsGroups="false" allowAnonymousLogons="false" />
                    </serviceCredentials>
                    <dataContractSerializer maxItemsInObjectGraph="100000000" />
                </behavior>

                <!-- BEHAVIOR FOR TRANSPORT SECURITY -->
                <behavior name="SecureBehavior">
                    <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true"/>
                    <serviceCredentials>
                        <clientCertificate>
                            <authentication certificateValidationMode="PeerTrust" />
                        </clientCertificate>
                        <serviceCertificate findValue="sfs-Test" x509FindType="FindBySubjectName" storeLocation="LocalMachine" storeName="My" />
                    </serviceCredentials>
                    <dataContractSerializer maxItemsInObjectGraph="100000000" />
                </behavior>

            </serviceBehaviors>
        </behaviors>

        <bindings>

            <!-- DEFINE BINDING -->
            <basicHttpBinding>
                <binding name="HttpBinding_AlphaSystem">
                    <security mode="Transport">
                        <transport clientCredentialType="Certificate" />
                    </security>
                </binding>
            </basicHttpBinding>

        </bindings>        
        <services>

            <!-- DEFINE SERVICE -->
            <service behaviorConfiguration="SecureBehavior" name="Alpha.Services.DeltaService.DeltaService">

                <!-- ENDPOINT FOR METADATA -->
                <endpoint address="mex" binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="" contract="IMetadataExchange" />

                <!-- ENDPOINT FOR DATA -->
                <endpoint address="" binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="HttpBinding_AlphaSystem" contract="Alpha.Services.DeltaService.IDeltaService"/>                    

                <!-- BASE ADDRESSES FOR SERVICE-->
                <host>
                    <baseAddresses>
                        <add baseAddress="http://SFS-111:20022/DeltaService" />
                        <add baseAddress="https://SFS-111:20023/DeltaService" />
                    </baseAddresses>
                </host>
            </service>

        </services>
    </system.serviceModel>
</configuration>
```

HERE'S MY CLIENT APP.CONFIG:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
    <system.diagnostics>
        <sources>
            <source name="System.ServiceModel" switchValue="Information, ActivityTracing" propagateActivity="true">
                <listeners>
                    <add name="traceListener" type="System.Diagnostics.XmlWriterTraceListener" initializeData="c:\tahseen\dd\WCFClient.svclog"    />
                </listeners>
            </source>
        </sources>
    </system.diagnostics>

    <system.serviceModel>

        <!-- DEFINE SECURE BEHAVIOR -->
        <behaviors>
            <endpointBehaviors>
                <behavior name="ClientBehavior">
                    <clientCredentials>
                        <clientCertificate findValue="sfs-Client" x509FindType="FindBySubjectName" storeLocation="LocalMachine" storeName="My" />
                        <serviceCertificate>
                            <authentication certificateValidationMode="PeerTrust"/>
                        </serviceCertificate>
                    </clientCredentials>
                </behavior>
            </endpointBehaviors>
        </behaviors>

        <bindings>
            <basicHttpBinding>
                <binding name="BasicHttpBinding_IDeltaService" closeTimeout="00:01:00" openTimeout="00:01:00" receiveTimeout="00:10:00" sendTimeout="00:01:00" allowCookies="false" 
        bypassProxyOnLocal="false" hostNameComparisonMode="StrongWildcard" maxBufferSize="65536" maxBufferPoolSize="524288" maxReceivedMessageSize="65536"
        messageEncoding="Text" textEncoding="utf-8" transferMode="Buffered" useDefaultWebProxy="true">
                    <readerQuotas maxDepth="32" maxStringContentLength="8192" maxArrayLength="16384"
                        maxBytesPerRead="4096" maxNameTableCharCount="16384" />
                    <security mode="Transport">
                        <transport clientCredentialType="Certificate" realm="" />
                    </security>
                </binding>
            </basicHttpBinding>
        </bindings>
        <client>
            <endpoint address="https://sfs-111:20023/DeltaService" binding="basicHttpBinding" behaviorConfiguration ="ClientBehavior"
                bindingConfiguration="BasicHttpBinding_IDeltaService" contract="DeltaService.IDeltaService"
                name="BasicHttpBinding_IDeltaService">
                <identity>
                    <dns value="sfs-Test" />
                </identity>
            </endpoint>
        </client>
    </system.serviceModel>
</configuration>
```

HERE'S MY SERVICE CODE:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.ServiceModel;
using System.ServiceModel.Description;

namespace Alpha.Services.DeltaService
{
    public class DeltaService : IDeltaService
    {
        public int timesTwo(int n)
        {
            return n * 2;
        }
    }

    [ServiceContract]
    interface IDeltaService
    {
        [OperationContract]
        int timesTwo(int n);
    }

    public class App
    {
        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            //DeltaService service = new DeltaService();
            ServiceHost serviceHost = new ServiceHost(typeof(DeltaService));
            serviceHost.Open();

            Console.WriteLine("Press any key to exit");
            Console.ReadKey();

            serviceHost.Close();
        }
    }
}
```

HERE'S MY CLIENT CODE:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;

namespace WCFClient
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            DeltaService.IDeltaService service = new DeltaService.DeltaServiceClient();

            int result = service.timesTwo(5);

            Console.WriteLine(result);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Are those tests running on the same machine? Do you have certificates correctly configured in Windows Certificate Store? Those PeerTrust settings don't work with HTTPS because HTTPS is handled directly by Windows operating system.

Comment: How do I check if the certificates are configured correctly? Also, if PeerTrust won't work, what should I change it to? Please excuse my ignorance, as I'm new to WCF and certificates.

Comment: Are those certificates self signed?

Comment: Sorry, I didn't create the certificates so can't say. How can I check? Or alternatively, would it be simpler to create new ones? If so, how would I do that?

Answer (score 2):

just for testing, try to disable ssl validation on the client:

http://webservices20.blogspot.com/2008/12/wcf-gotcha-disabling-ssl-validation.html

```
using System.Net;
using System.Net.Security;
using System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates;
...
ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback = new RemoteCertificateValidationCallback(OnValidationCallback); 
...
public static bool OnValidationCallback(object sender, X509Certificate cert, X509Chain chain, SslPolicyErrors errors)
{ 
return true;
}
```

Comment: Maybe I'm missing something, but isn't this defeating the whole point of the exercise? How do I get the ssl validation to work without disabling it?

Comment: this will help to determine if the problem is really with the certificate validaiton or there is some other problem. if it is the former than you need to install the certificate issuer x.509 in your trusted certificate authority